# can I sign files with pre-made sig file?

Tags: file, security, sign, gpg-signature

I have a file that I need to sign with a sig key that I got from a site.
I was able to convert the sig file to `.txt` and to `.asc` but could not use it to sign.

Now it is to my understanding that sig files could be created when decrypting a file as a stand alone key for verifying the integrity of that file, but is there no way to use it (or the converted one or the key in the `.txt` file) to sign it with ?

**note:** when trying to import the sig file I get the error `"no valid openpgp data found"`

any help or explanation is greatly appreciated, as i have little knowledge in `Linux`.

**edit:** as for what format was the `.sig` key in, I don't have an idea and don't know how to know that. I was able to convert it to `.txt` using `gpg --armor` command and got the following :

-----BEGIN PGP ARMORED FILE-----

Comment: Use "gpg --dearmor" for unpacking

AFKsfPJNZWlOU4y39MRt1ivJOryGT9EpeB9J4C2k9hWdAprq7rERe3BoNq5eb6YV
0PZOMexcPg3YiH82KSEKD5PqFKxb+FGRxSIJZWkILXA9ujd/kTEUgkWcYjyEGDrd
jMxsmoVW0QxtP6DpapLMJW0SXmiPfjDBGZCgnpG0N+8==CO0K

-----END PGP ARMORED FILE-----

can't I use the text I got to somehow sign the file ? the main reason I need to do this is to sign a `.zip` file that I'll next import into a program which will only extract it if it was correctly signed.
I hope that I'm making sense.

Comment: Can you provide some context? What format was your "sig key" in? How did you "convert it to txt"? Are you sure your "sig key" was not actually a signature? You obviously can't use a signature to sign other files, what would be the point then? Are you even trying to write software (in what language then?), or just trying to get it done it Linux (in which case this is off-topic on SO).

Comment: I add some context, hope you get what I'm trying to do. I am not writing a software, just trying to sign the file using Linux as I could not do it in windows. and yes I am positive the "sig key" is not a signature. Thx for your time @GaborLengyel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the md5 checksum from the captured go ahead and flash. to your own. Thus tricking the flasher that the file is right. Inside the Captured File from IOS was the original IOS Checksum. Change that orgiinal md5 checksum to your new md5 checksum. Turn fiddler on with app auto response. meaning everytime the program trys to speak with the server it gets your new response with your md5check sum.  It has been 6 months since I have completed that project. I will re-look at the resigning procedure. I do know Some files require brute force to obtain password to be resigned, while others are less evasive.

With the method of using the captured IOS server repsonse, then changing the md5 to match yours, you will flash. Test if the Phone will accept without signing.

I will be watching if this solved your problem or if i need to further investigate. The files I changes seems as if it was less security monitored.

Comment: thanks for your response, yes I captured the response via `Fiddler`, changed the `md5` to the new value, turned on auto response and was able to push the modded file but it failed in the middle (I guess at the extracting point on the device).
I then tried another software called `libi - idevicerestore` which allowed me to push the file without verifying the `md5` and gave me detailed description of the process. It stated that the failure happened due to unsigned file (after being extracted and pushed).
thanks again for your time. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so I guess there is no way to do it, right ? @MichaelSmith

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing Apple Added to the security measures to counter act, the way I did it. So far the only ways I have found would be to possibly bruteforce for a password with the sig file, OR create XCode developers profile. And sign the file yourself. That may not work. Depending on file changed. They have blocked the way I found months ago. I checked with my apple iphone the original phone I got rid of unwanted security measures for a complete jailBroken Phone. No backend information gathering, and so on. When Pushing the finished files, that worked before, and currently on the phone, it failed. So apple must be storing the proper signatures for each file to be check during installation. I would try the xCode Developers profile to sign the file. then Attempt to locate the signature source file stored within the Files SomeWhere. This is as far as i have gotten.

I would love to be able to re-crack the apple ios however with more recent projects dealing with Mass Deeplearing AI for Stock Exchange evaluations, diversity, buy/sell calculations. I Truely don't have the time to spend days on end testing and Trying out different methods. Bruteforcing existing sig file will take hours possibly days depending on system. Xcode Developer profile sig Should work in theory however I could be wrong.  Good luck!